# HiddenInput attribute causes runtime error in HiddenInput.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

## Update

So, I was looking at the wrong file all along.  My project had two HiddenInput.cshtml files, one in the displayTemplate folder and one in the EditorTemplates.  My brain wasn't making the connection I was looking at two different folders.

---

So this seems like a strange error to recieve when adding the hiddenInput attribute to a property in my ViewModel...

My guess to the cause is that because I have my ViewModels,Controllers, and Models in 3 separate projects.  However, I made sure System.Data.Linq is referenced in all three when I was trying to debug this issue.

> c:\proj\Adirondack.search\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\HiddenInput.cshtml(9):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

### ViewModel

```
public class BasicSearchViewModel 
{
    public BasicSearchViewModel()
    {
        SalesFrom = new DateTime(1974, 1, 1);
        SalesTo = DateTime.Today;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Owner", ShortName = "Owner", Prompt = "Enter Owner"), DataType(DataType.Text)] 
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Account Number", ShortName = "Strap", Prompt = "Enter Account Number"), DataType(DataType.Text)] 
    public string STRAP { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address", ShortName = "Addr.", Prompt = "Enter full address"), DataType(DataType.Text)] 
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //public bool HasPool { get; set; }


    public string Location { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }


    public bool Pool { get; set; }

    public bool Tennis { get; set; }

    public bool Dock { get; set; }

    public bool SeaWall { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Sales From")]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime),"1/1/1974","12/31/2050")]        
    public DateTime SalesFrom { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Sales To")]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1974", "12/31/2050")]
    public DateTime SalesTo { get; set; }


    public int? SaleAmountFrom { get; set; }
    public int? SaleAmountTo { get; set; }


    public bool VacantLand { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public PagedList<ParcelResultItemViewModel> SearchResults { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? page { get; set; }

}
```

### Search.cshtml

```
@using Search.Helpers;
@using Search.Components.Html.ViewModels;
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@model BasicSearchViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";

}

@Html.ActionLink("Advanced", "AdvancedSearch")
@Html.ActionLink("Tangible", "Search", "Tangible")

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Parcel",  FormMethod.Get, new { id = "searchForm" }))
{

<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x)</div>

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
     <input type="submit" value="Refine" />




        <h2>Results</h2>
<strong>Showing the first @Model.SearchResults.TotalItemCount of  @ViewData["count"] results found </strong>

<table>
<tr>
<th>STRAP</th>
<th>SITUS</th>
<th>PROPERTY USE</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.STRAP) 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SITUS)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SUBDIVISION_PROPERTY_USE)
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            @Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Details", new { id = item.STRAP })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    @foreach (var owner in item.OWNERS.Take(2).OrderBy(x => x.LN_NUM))
    {
       @owner.NAME<br /> 
    }
    </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<pre>
@HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Model.AsQueryString())
</pre>   

@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults, page => Url.Action("search", 
    new {Page = page,   
        owner = Model.OwnerName,
        AccountNumber = Model.STRAP,
        Address = Model.Address,
        Location = Model.Location,
        ZipCode = Model.ZipCode,
        Pool = Model.Pool,
        Tennis = Model.Tennis,
        Dock = Model.Dock,
        SeaWall = Model.SeaWall,
        SalesFrom = Model.SalesFrom,
        SalesTo = Model.SalesTo,
        SaleAmountFrom = Model.SaleAmountFrom,
        SaleAmountTo = Model.SaleAmountTo,
        VacantLand = Model.VacantLand          
         }

    ))

}
```

Comment: The error is in your view (cshtml file), not your viewmodel, model, or controller. =)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You mean the code for Search.cshtml correct?  Because I didn't write HiddenInput.cshtml that is part of the Microsoft MVC framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `LINQ` expression in your razoe view. You need to have proper namespaces imported to your view to use the LINQ function.

Add using `System.Linq;` statement to your view.

Comment: This was the very first thing I tried yesterday.  I added that to both Search.cshtml AND Microsoft's HiddenInput.cshtml.  I tried it again just now.  Same error. Just takes 40 seconds to load now.  As soon as I remove the attribute [HiddenInput] from the ViewModel the site runs fine.  So, Unless Microsoft's HiddenInput.cshtml requires linq. I really don't see why I would need to add a reference to linq

Comment: what is hiddeninput.cshtml ? where did you get that ?

Comment: It is part of the MVC Framework EditorTemplates.  It can be overridden by creating a template with that name, but it is actually inside the Assembly. ps.  I'm not overriding it.

Comment: See update.  You were right. A Nuget package had installed a 'fancier' HiddenInput.cshtml.  I deleted it, so now no need to reference linq.